# For WCAG AA standard when marking up a <label> element near <select> element, does the <label> element need to be visible?

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag2.0

Looking into the accessibility criteria for  elements for WCAG AA.

I am using the following pages as reference

http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=91

http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=208

http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=209

Our intention is to either wrap the `<label>` around `<select>` or have it as a sibling.

Two-fold question, does the label have to be visible?  And if so is there a pixel recommendation to compliment the element?  We intend to keep it close if it's visible, but I want to feed back to the design team

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `label` element needs to be visible. There is no pixel recommendation regarding its placement, but it is crucial that it is visually associated with the control (like the `select` element here). After all, probably over 99% of visitors will use common graphic browsers, and many visitors will have cognitive or other difficulties in understanding the structure of a form.

You should use the [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) recommendation and associated documents, rather than some accessibility checker, as the basic reference. In particular, the “Understanding WCAG 2.0” document says, at [H44: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/H44): “This technique is sufficient for Success Criteria 1.1.1, 1.3.1 and 4.1.2 whether or not the label element is visible. That is, it may be hidden using CSS. However, for Success Criterion 3.3.2, the label element must be visible since it provides assistance to all users who need help understanding the purpose of the field.”

[Criterion 3.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html) says: “Labels or instructions are provided when content requires user input.” Obviously, they are not “provided” if they are not visible to a person who uses vision-based browsing (that is, most of us).

The WCAG 2.0 document also say that due to problems in some browsers, an “explicit” `label` element (i.e., a `label` element with a `for` attribute) is preferable to “implicit” (`label` element that contains the control it is associated with it). It’s also more logical: a control is not part of its label.

Comment: +1 for the first 3 paragraphs, obviously. In regards to explicit/implicit and associated or not via `for`/`id`: the important part is having label and form element associated via `for`/`id`; siblings or ancestor/descendant then isn't a problem. I tend to prefer a select into its label as it allows to have a hint or error message on the other side of the form element or below and still have it into the label. `<label><span>The real label</span> <input type="text"> <span>OH no you did something wrong</span> </label>` in short. Will be read by screen readers in "form mode"